# Python: key pressed event ignores conditional statement

Tags: python, matplotlib

I’m a novice working on my first python project.  I started with this "poly_editor.py" example from the matplotlib documentation since my program is doing similar things with an interactive graph.  I’ve commented the 3 locations where I made additions and modifications.  Basically, I just made the list of vertices (self.d) visible so I could check to not add more than 100.

```
"""
This is an example to show how to build cross-GUI applications using
matplotlib event handling to interact with objects on the canvas

"""
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.artist import Artist
from matplotlib.mlab import dist_point_to_segment


class PolygonInteractor(object):
    """
    An polygon editor.

    Key-bindings

      't' toggle vertex markers on and off.  When vertex markers are on,
          you can move them, delete them

      'd' delete the vertex under point

      'i' insert a vertex at point.  You must be within epsilon of the
          line connecting two existing vertices

    """

    showverts = True
    epsilon = 5  # max pixel distance to count as a vertex hit

    def __init__(self, ax, poly):
        if poly.figure is None:
            raise RuntimeError('You must first add the polygon to a figure or canvas before defining the interactor')
        self.ax = ax
        canvas = poly.figure.canvas
        self.poly = poly


        ######### added ########
        self.d = []
        ######## end add #######


        x, y = zip(*self.poly.xy)
        self.line = Line2D(x, y, marker='o', markerfacecolor='r', animated=True)
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)
        #self._update_line(poly)

        cid = self.poly.add_callback(self.poly_changed)
        self._ind = None  # the active vert

        canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.draw_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.key_press_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.button_release_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.motion_notify_callback)
        self.canvas = canvas

    def draw_callback(self, event):
        self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)

    def poly_changed(self, poly):
        'this method is called whenever the polygon object is called'
        # only copy the artist props to the line (except visibility)
        vis = self.line.get_visible()
        Artist.update_from(self.line, poly)
        self.line.set_visible(vis)  # don't use the poly visibility state

    def get_ind_under_point(self, event):
        'get the index of the vertex under point if within epsilon tolerance'


        #################### changed code ######################
        # display coords
        xy = np.asarray(self.poly.xy)
        xyt = self.poly.get_transform().transform(xy)
        xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]
        self.d = np.sqrt((xt - event.x)**2 + (yt - event.y)**2)
        indseq = np.nonzero(np.equal(self.d, np.amin(self.d)))[0]
        ind = indseq[0]
        print(len(self.d))
        if self.d[ind] >= self.epsilon:
            ind = None
        #################### end changes #######################


        return ind

    def button_press_callback(self, event):
        'whenever a mouse button is pressed'
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)

    def button_release_callback(self, event):
        'whenever a mouse button is released'
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        self._ind = None

    def key_press_callback(self, event):
        'whenever a key is pressed'
        if not event.inaxes:
            return
        if event.key == 't':
            self.showverts = not self.showverts
            self.line.set_visible(self.showverts)
            if not self.showverts:
                self._ind = None
        elif event.key == 'd':
            ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)
            if ind is not None:
                self.poly.xy = [tup for i, tup in enumerate(self.poly.xy) if i != ind]
                self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
        elif event.key == 'i':


            ########### added ###########
            if len(self.d) < 100:
            ########## end add ##########


                xys = self.poly.get_transform().transform(self.poly.xy)
                p = event.x, event.y  # display coords
                for i in range(len(xys) - 1):
                    s0 = xys[i]
                    s1 = xys[i + 1]
                    d = dist_point_to_segment(p, s0, s1)
                    if d <= self.epsilon:
                        self.poly.xy = np.array(
                            list(self.poly.xy[:i]) +
                            [(event.xdata, event.ydata)] +
                            list(self.poly.xy[i:]))
                        self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
                        break

        self.canvas.draw()

    def motion_notify_callback(self, event):
        'on mouse movement'
        if not self.showverts:
            return
        if self._ind is None:
            return
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        if event.button != 1:
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata

        self.poly.xy[self._ind] = x, y
        if self._ind == 0:
            self.poly.xy[-1] = x, y
        elif self._ind == len(self.poly.xy) - 1:
            self.poly.xy[0] = x, y
        self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))

        self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

    theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
    r = 1.5

    xs = r*np.cos(theta)
    ys = r*np.sin(theta)

    poly = Polygon(list(zip(xs, ys)), animated=True)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.add_patch(poly)
    p = PolygonInteractor(ax, poly)

    #ax.add_line(p.line)
    ax.set_title('Click and drag a point to move it')
    ax.set_xlim((-2, 2))
    ax.set_ylim((-2, 2))
    plt.show()
```

The problem is:  if you click on an edge and hold down the “i” key to insert vertices, it will just continue to add beyond 100, ignoring the “if len(self.d) < 100:” statement.

I found this “bug” by accidentally leaning on the keyboard… lol.  Is there any way to fix this behavior?  My current work around is to bind it to the release event, but rapidly pressing the key can still cause the issue.  My next option is to just allow additional points by a popup menu I guess, but I’d prefer a solution to a work around.

Comment: I ran the program and there aren't any points. How do I add a point? How to replicate this bug?

Comment: I notice in the block of code that handles the "i" keypress, you don't actually modify self.d in any way.  When you press the "i" key repeatedly, the if statement will continue to evaluate True every time.  Messing around with a 200 line program that depends on several third-party libraries seems like an incredibly hard way to learn a new language.  But that's your business.

Comment: Ah, good catch!  Thought I had reproduced my issue using the original sample, but my problem was actually that I had accidentally deleted the 'break' statement at some point causing additional points to be created for each vertex within epsilon tolerance.  Probably leaning on my keyboard again... My mistake.